# Fetch data from table in mysql that must have corresponding records in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to show records from table name station where station have at least one song in song table.
Table structure

```
station
station_id
stration_name
station_description

song
song_id
station_id
song_location
```

Please suggest me the way to form query that shows me station data which have songs in song table.please specify a way that do not returns record with corresponding songs zero count.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html). You could join your stations table with your songs table by `stations.station_id` and `songs.station_id`. This will work because [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) only return rows for which the join-predicate is satisfied.

I've made an example available at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7db01/9), but I do recommend spending a few minutes understanding mechanics of [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT something 
           FROM somewhere 
           JOIN somewhere_else 
             ON somewhere_else.other_thing = somewhere.thing;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables together at `station_id`.
It looks like each song is linked to a spesific station. Meaning where these ID (`station_id`) is equal, the station has this song...